# Traversing JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, socket.io

I have the following code in an HTML file:

```
socket.on('message',function(data) {
          console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
          $('#data').append('<br />'+data.toString('utf8'));
        });
```

The server at certain points sends a string or sends a JSON object to the client however when I try to use JSON syntax to access the data eg/ `$('#data').append(data.people[0].name])` it throws an error saying people is undefined. I know the data being sent is valid.  How do I get my function to understand its dealing with JSON?

Comment: What's showing `console.log(data);` on the client side?

Comment: `data.people[0].name` is **not** "JSON syntax". If the response is JSON, then you have to parse it to a JavaScript object first.

Comment: I get Received message from server [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `data` is coming back as a JSON string, then you probably need to parse it as JSON first. This can be done using the `$.parseJSON` method like so:

```
socket.on('message',function(data) {
    var myData = $.parseJSON(data);
    // the remainder of your code
});
```

You can find more information on `$.parseJSON` in the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). Also worth noting is that if the browser that your code is running in has a native implementation of `JSON.parse`, the `$.parseJSON` method will use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
socket.json.send({data:'pepew'})
```

On the server side to send json, it will automatically be decoded by socket.io. And if you want to send json to the server you can simply do

```
socket.json.send({data:'boom'});
```

:D same api

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON data first:

```
json = JSON.parse(data);
json.people[0].name;
```

or at least use:

```
json = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

Comment: If Jquery is being used, there is no need to use eval. Jquery can use its implementation of `JSON.parse`, or the browsers native implementation.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. Sure, its better to use the jQuery implementation... eval is evil ;)